# Get a firebase ref to a set of conditional data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Given above json table, is there any way to **get reference** to the collections (not each items individually) of `transactedItems` with `transactionId = t-001`?

I imagined something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("transactedItems").
        orderByChild("transactionId").
        equalTo("t-001").
        getRef();
```

But when I tried code above, it returns all transactedItems exists in the table.

So, **is it possible** to get reference to such **set of conditional data** (not individual data)? If yes, how?

Comment: Didn't you ask that a few hours ago? Why did you delete that question and open a new one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237624/how-to-get-firebase-ref-to-the-actual-objects-based-on-a-list-of-ids-in-parent?noredirect=1#comment67748787_40237624

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I deleted it because I think I already figure it out, but it turned out I was wrong. So, I decided to post it again with clearer / simpler details. I didn't know that I can undelete a question.

Comment: Next time you figure out the answer to your own question, post it as a self answer. That way others can benefit.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen got it. thank you for the tip